# Client Error: SNI is required Client Error: SSL is required

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

- Python 2.7.6
- pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python2.7)
- pip.conf is not exist in system
- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
- Release:   14.04
- Codename:       trusty

**whatever i do with pip installl i got error**

```
Downloading/unpacking <package>
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement <package>
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for <package>
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

**python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.get_default_verify_paths())"**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_default_verify_paths'

**pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org  -vvv**

```
no such option: --trusted-host
```

**pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ linkchecker**

```
Downloading/unpacking linkchecker
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/ uses an insecure transport scheme (http). Consider using https if pypi.python.org has it available
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement linkchecker
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for linkchecker
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

**in /root/.pip/pip.log**

```
/usr/bin/pip run on Sun Aug  6 13:10:22 2023
Downloading/unpacking linkchecker
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/: 403 Client Error: SSL is required
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/ when looking for download links for linkchecker
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: 403 Client Error: SSL is required
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for linkchecker
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for linkchecker:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/
  http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/ uses an insecure transport scheme (http). Consider using https if pypi.python.org has it available
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/: 403 Client Error: SSL is required
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/ when looking for download links for linkchecker
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement linkchecker
Cleaning up...
  Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_root...
No distributions at all found for linkchecker
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for linkchecker
```

**So i got errors**

- Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: 403 Client Error: SNI is required
- Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/linkchecker/: 403 Client Error: SSL is required

**python get-pip.py**

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<21.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip<21.0
/tmp/tmp6o8w38/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:164: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
WARNING: Certificate did not match expected hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Jul 30 16:48:42 2024 GMT', 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org'), ('DNS', 'python.org')), 'subject': ((('commonName', u'www.python.org'),),)}
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org', 'python.org'",),)) - skipping
```

**apt list | grep python2**

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface yet. Use with caution in scripts.

idle-python2.7/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 all
libpython2.7/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3]
libpython2.7-dbg/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 amd64
libpython2.7-dev/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3]
libpython2.7-minimal/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3]
libpython2.7-stdlib/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3]
libpython2.7-testsuite/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 all
libqgispython2.0.1/trusty,trusty-updates 2.0.1-2build2 amd64
python2-pyro4/trusty 4.23-1 all
python2.7/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3]
python2.7-dbg/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 amd64
python2.7-dev/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3]
python2.7-doc/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 all
python2.7-examples/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 all
python2.7-minimal/trusty-updates,trusty-security 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.5 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.6-8ubuntu0.3]
```

so i cant upgrade to python 2.7.9

**easy_install also not work**

```
easy_install pyOpenSSL
Searching for pyOpenSSL
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyOpenSSL/
Couldn't find index page for 'pyOpenSSL' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pyOpenSSL
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pyOpenSSL')
```

So how to fix thoose errors, upgrade to python 2.7.9 and upgrade pip to version newest than 1.5.4?
and how then update version in venv too?

Comment: Try `pyenv`; see https://serverfault.com/a/732785/438742 (well, you've already saw this). Try to install from sources (but you need to install a lot of libraries): https://renoirboulanger.com/blog/2015/04/upgrade-python-2-7-9-ubuntu-14-04-lts-making-deb-package/ Found in https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=ubuntu+trusty+python2.7

Comment: i tryed, error on this ./configure --prefix /usr/local/lib/python2.7.9 --enable-ipv6, checking build system type... mkdir: cannot create directory '/tmp/cg22467-13142': No such file or directory

Comment: What about installing with `conda`? https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python/files?version=2.7.15 . Install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), activate it, install Python 2.7 `conda create -c conda-forge -n py27 python=2.7.15` , activate the virtual environment: `conda activate py27`

Comment: As for the error "mkdir: cannot create directory '/tmp/…'" — does `/tmp` have all necessary access bits? `ls -dl /tmp` must return `drwxrwxrwt`. Do you have enough free disk space on the partition where `/tmp` resides?